# Why can't the visual studio compiler find certain header files while intellisense can?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am working on a project in Visual Studio 2010 and I need to include some header files from another location on my PC.

In the project properties I have added the required folder to the c++ "Additional Includes" field. When adding these files to a .h or a .cpp file I can use auto complete to find all of them, however when I go to actually use some symbol that is defined in this package the compiler can not find that symbol and intellisense marks it as bad.

When I right click on one of these symbols and select "Go To Declaration" the IDE successfully loads the file and takes me to the line where that symbol is defined.

As per the advice of some other answers I have deleted my intellisense database files, they were not regenerated upon loading the project.

What should I do next?

---

Some other details about the environment, all of my folders are protected by Rational ClearCase. The files I am trying to include are located on another "drive". I need to include one file and it should include all of the rest for the library. The specific library I am working with is the AVT Vimba 1.2 SDK.

Comment: `What should I do next?` My opinion, try visual assist.

Comment: Auto-completing an #include is very simple, just a file search.  Using a "symbol" is an entirely different kettle of fish, an #if can skip a definition for example.  What you can do about it is document your problem properly.  At least post the first few compile errors.

Comment: While looking through the header files it doesn't appear as though any vital definitions are getting skipped by #ifs, however while double checking for this response I realized that it was a namespace issue that wasn't documented or shown in any manuals.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment on the question, while exploring the files for #if directives I discovered some namespace declarations that don't appear to be documented in this SDK's manuals.